# How to perform form validation with fields that are pre-populated via ng-model in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

Suppose I have a form with required fields.  I am pre-populating these fields via ng-model with data from my controller.  On the submit button for this form, there is an ng-disabled property that checks for $invalid, like this:

`<button ng-click="next()" ng-disabled="form.is.$invalid">Next</button>`

The problem I am running into is that when the page initially loads, the button is disabled and the validity of the fields are not being checked unless I go back and manually delete each field and re-type their values.

I would like to know how to check for this validity on page load so that if I have some data loading into the fields via ng-model, it will still recognize the required fields as valid.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, in this little example it works
http://jsfiddle.net/dnugq56d/
the button is disabled at the beginning.
After 3s the values will be populated and then the button is enabled

Comment: Is this what is trying to be accomplished,  that essentially, one wants to configure the form and the NgModelController that the input field is invalid due to a value being required, and using the form's $invalid property to indicate the button's active state, yet have it NOT have $invalid true initially, even though during the 3 sec timeout it is obviously invalid?  If one wants to do that, there are options.  Rather than use $invalid directly, add a function to the scope in which when loading data, the active state is true, then after loading the state is driven validity state of the form.

Comment: This [plunk](http://plnkr.co/HrhFgPAnOB4DbFOjHvLR) incorporates a timeout, is this what is actually being asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this question.  I ended up re-writing the form to check for validation on button click (instead of using ng-disabled.)

When the button is clicked, fields are checked and error messages are shown via ng-show.  In the controller, check for properties in form.$error.  If an error was added to this object, then errors exist.  The logic looks like this:

```
$scope.buttonClick = function () {
    var obj = $scope.form.$error, hasErrors = false, key;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    }

    if (!hasErrors) {
        // proceed
    } 
};
```

Comment: Is there a solution like this for angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

I think some more example code needs to be added here, because I believe what you want to do is straight-forward with angular.  In the snippit above, did you actually name your form as "form", e.g. ...?  You need to name the form for it to be referrable.  Also, if you are checking for the validity of the entire form, assuming you named the form, I think the following should work:

```
<form name="userForm" novalidate ng-controller="userController">
  <input name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" required/>
  <input name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" required/>
  <button ng-click="next()" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Next</button>
</form>
```

And the javascript code is like this:

```
var app = angular.module("userApp", [])

.controller("userController", function($scope) {
  var user = {
    firstname: "Willy",
    lastname: "Nilly"
  }
  $scope.user = user;

  $scope.next = function() {
    console.log("next")
  }
});
```

Here is a link to the corresponding [plunker](http://plnkr.co/5vzgwEqA6mUg50xBFl97)  Is this what you are looking for?

Or, are you having an issue with the data being loaded from a remote call and while the promise is being resolved the button is not enabled?  Please clarify if this is not what you are looking for.